# Harmonic series in python

Tags: python, math

Does anyone know how to code the [Harmonic Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) in python?

```
H(n) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n
```

Note: We're not allowed to import from predefined modules. The output must be the numerator and the denominator of the answer in fraction form (lowest terms).

so here's my code for this harmonic series.

```
n = input("Enter n:")  

def harmonic(n):  
    a=1  
    b=1  
    for d in range(2, n+1):  
            a = a*d+b  
            b = b*d  
            return (a,b)  
            x == max(a,b)%min(a, b)  
            if x == 0:  
                y=min(a,b)  
                return y  
            else:  
                y=min(a,b)/x  
                return y  
            a=a/y  
            b=b/y  
            return (a,b)  
print harmonic(n)
```

what's wrong? Whatever I input,  the output is always (3,2)

Comment: You always `return (a,b)` at the first iteration.

Comment: As @Scharron said, you always return `a, b`. Notice that you have an `if...else` bloc that gets executed no matter what. Both branches return a value. So your `for` loop never goes around more than once.

Comment: Hint: You probably want to break it down into 2 steps. 1) add a bunch of fractions up (to do this, you will want to be able to find the lcm of 2 fractions) and 2) reduce the fractions. Why not break them down into separate functions?

Comment: So.. what should i do to make it better? what should i use in place of return? Thanks :)

Comment: @JoelCornett . we're not allowed to import fractions :(((

Comment: @user1950302: I didn't say anything about importing fractions. I meant that you would probably have to write a function that found the least common multiple of a pair of numbers (One of them being the numerator, and one the denominator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to check your attempt twice - and inserted a simple gcd (in the middle of the your original code)

```
n = input("Enter n:")

def harmonic(n): #original harmonic series
     a=1
     b=1
     for d in range(2, n+1):
         a = a*d+b
         b = b*d
     return(a,b)


def harmonic_lt(n): #_lt: harmonic series with lowest terms
                    #not pythonic, but simple
    a=1
    b=1
    for d in range(2, n+1):
        a = a*d+b
        b = b*d

    y=a
    x=b
    while x > 0:
        re = y % x
        y = x
        x = re

    a=a/y
    b=b/y
    return(a,b)

print harmonic(n)
print harmonic_lt(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the denominator by finding the lowest common multiple of the numbers 1..n.

The nominator will then be the sum of all values `denominator/x` with x being all values from 1..n.

Here's some code:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    """Return greatest common divisor using Euclid's Algorithm."""
    while b:      
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def lcm(a, b):
    """Return lowest common multiple."""
    return a * b // gcd(a, b)

def lcmm(args):
    """Return lcm of args."""   
    return reduce(lcm, args)


def harmonic(n):
    lowest_common_multiple = lcmm(range(1,n))
    nominator = sum([lowest_common_multiple/i for i in range(1,n)])
    greatest_common_denominator = gcd(lowest_common_multiple, nominator)
    return nominator/greatest_common_denominator, lowest_common_multiple/greatest_common_denominator

print harmonic(7)
print harmonic(10)
print harmonic(20)
```

Comment: The OP says that "The output must be the numerator and the denominator of the answer in fraction form (lowest terms)" - I don't think he wants a generator

Comment: Was still in the flow... sorry for the confusion

Comment: Mmmm... This isn't the harmonic series.

Comment: I don't this is is quite right -- you could still wind up with cases where the numerator and denominator have a common factor.  For example, `harmonic(7) == (147, 60)`, but should really be `(49, 20)`.  Probably it would suffice to divide each of your returned `n,d` by `gcd(n,d)`.

Comment: You probably want to a) explain your code to OP (who claims to be a python beginner), and b) rename your `lcm` function, as it doesn't always produce the least common multiple of two numbers, rather it produces the strict multiple of 2 numbers.

Comment: ...Never mind about (b), for some reason, my browser rendered `// gcd(a, b)` in comment colors, and I realize that it is *not* a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your review, but I won't put any more effort in this. I corrected my Code, and @sidi said all that was to say.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, you are returning when d = 2 i.e. (1 + 1/2), it should be outside of the for loop.

Here's a code I wrote for doing the same:

```
#!Python2.7
def gcd(a, b):
    if b: return gcd(b, a%b)
    return a

def lcm(a, b):
    return a*b/gcd(a, b)

def start():
    n = int(raw_input())
    ans = reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0]*lcm(x[1],y[1])/x[1]+y[0]*lcm(x[1],y[1])/y[1], lcm(x[1],y[1])),[(1,x) for x in xrange(1,n+1)])
    _gcd = gcd(ans[0], ans[1])
    print (ans[0]/_gcd, ans[1]/_gcd)

start()
```

If you want to avoid using `reduce`, `lamda` and list comprehensions:

```
#!Python2.7
def gcd(a, b):
    if b: return gcd(b, a%b)
    return a

def lcm(a, b):
    assert a != 0
    assert b != 0
    return a*b/gcd(a, b)

def next(x, y):
    lcmxy = lcm(x[1], y[1])
    return (x[0]*lcmxy/x[1]+y[0]*lcmxy/y[1], lcmxy)

def start():
    n = int(raw_input())
    curr = (1,1)
    for x in xrange(2,n+1):
        curr = next(curr, (1,x))
    _gcd = gcd(curr[0], curr[1]) 
    print (curr[0]/_gcd, curr[1]/_gcd)

start()
```

Comment: This won't necessarily give the reduced values: e.g. `(147, 60)`.

Comment: Thank you so muchhh :)) By the way, what's the purpose of "assert"? thanks :)

Comment: They are a convenient way to debug. In my code, if a or b were 0, it would throw an AssertionError.

Comment: uhm.. by the way, what's the meaning of this syntax ? n*=1.0? thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Harmonic series:

```
1/1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n == (n!/1 + n!/2 + ... + n!/n)/n!
```

therefore you can do:

```
nom = reduce(lambda s, x: s*x, xrange(1, n+1),1)   # n!
denom = sum([nom / x for x in xrange(1, n+1)])
```

Then you need to do gcd-reduction on `nom` and `denom`.
Use the version from Thorsten Kranz.

Note that this way only one call to `gcd` is needed!

**Example:**

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:      
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a


def harmonic(n):
    nom = reduce(lambda s, x: s*x, xrange(1,n+1), 1)   # n!
    denom = sum([nom / x for x in xrange(1, n+1)])
    f = gcd(denom, nom)
    return (denom / f), (nom / f)


print harmonic(10)
print harmonic(20)

(7381, 2520)
(55835135, 15519504)
```

Comment: thank you :) by the way, what do we mean when we use the term reduce? what does it give as an output? thanks.

Comment: @user1950302, first of all, thanks for finally accepting this answer -- compared to the answer of @sidi and @ThorstenKranz (both are correct and elegant!) has this answer the advantage of calling `gcd` just once -- I believe its therefore faster.

Comment: [reduce](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) is a concept from functional programming. Here it is called `reduce(function(x, y), iterable, initial_value)`. It starts by evaluating `result = function(initial_value, iterable[0])`. Then it repeats `result = function(result, iterable[i])` until all elements from iterable are used. The final value for result is then returned. So if `n=3` then `nom` would be evaluated to `nom = (1*1*2*3)` where the first `1` is the initializer. This is of course `3!`.

Answer (score 0):

> You always return (a,b) at the first iteration. – Scharron"

Return always ends a function. If you return (a,b), the rest of the code is unreachable

Comment: So,, what should i do?? I'm so confused :'(